# Ruby Program to find the largest of a bunch of numbers (input specified by user)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to learn the concept on how to get the largest number, out of those specified by the user.And there can be 'n' numbers specified by the user.

Comment: You should give specific example of what is your requirement. what are your models or users give what type of inputs

Comment: be clear on the Question,use guidelines http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Do you want a Ruby code? like, user gave input from the console and your program returns the largest number from the given inputs?

Comment: yes,also with its explanation.Emu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
puts "Enter Number of inputs"
n = gets.chomp.to_i
puts "the numbers"
a = [] # store the numbers in an array
for i in (0...n)
  i = gets.chomp.to_i
  a.push(i)
end
a.sort # sort function to sort the array, the last value will be then the largest
puts a[n-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

The Array class of ruby has a max method which gives the maximum of all the numbers in an array.
For example,

```
[23,65,2,32,1].max
=> 65
```

There is a similar min method which gives the minimum of all the numbers.

```
[23,65,2,32,1].min
=> 1
```